# How to create modified date time in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, datetime

I need to create a list of datetime as presented in the attached Figure in Matlab, but I am not getting it.. so far I have done:

```
t1 = datetime(2016, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0);
t2 = datetime(2018, 12, 31, 23, 45, 0);
tinc = 15; 
t = t1:minutes(tinc):t2;
```

But it gives me "01-Apr-2016 00:00:00"

Instead, I need:

2016-04-01 00:00:00
2016-04-01 00:15:00
...
2018-12-31 23:45:00

Can someone explain to me how can I do it?

(The +01:00 is for daytime savings days that I can append later I guess).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Format` option with the desired specifier:

```
>> t= datetime(t1:minutes(tinc):t2,'Format','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS');
>> t(1:2)

ans = 

  1×2 datetime array

   2016-04-01 00:00:00   2016-04-01 00:15:00
```

You can find more information on the Display Format for datetime [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-display-format-of-date-and-time-arrays.html#buhb5in-1).